# How to take all questions from a tag using data explorer?

Tags: sql

In [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) I try sql query in order to take all questions related to a tag (there is an upper limit 50000).

```
The query is this:
Select Posts.id, creationdate,tags,owneruserid,answercount
FROM Tags, Posts
WHERE TagName = 'scala'
```

However the results are not related to the tag. Any idea why this could happen?

Comment: This question isn't a mysql question. It's better suite for the meta site. Voting to move to meta.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

TagId 3143 = Scala

```
SELECT P.id, creationdate,tags,owneruserid,answercount
FROM TAGS  AS T
JOIN POSTTAGS AS PT
ON T.ID = PT.TAGID
JOIN POSTS AS P
ON PT.POSTID = P.ID
WHERE PT.TAGID = 3143
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/875322

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed the join condition in your query. Please check below query.

```
Select Posts.id,      creationdate,tags,owneruserid,answercount
    FROM Tags join Posts
    on Tags.join_column = Posts.join_column
    WHERE TagName = 'scala'
```

`join_column` is the `column` on which `join` has to be made like `Tags.id= Posts.id`. In this `id` is the `join_column`.

Comment: Thank you. I receive this error if I try it `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.`